# Facebook coding

Tags: fbml

I'm trying to make a facebook application. Something like 'Gift your friends' and after some user action on it, 'check your gift' or something like that must be posted to that person's friends wall. How to do it? i saw many applications do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that, however you don't want to use fbml for that at all since it is deprecated.

1. Become an app developer. See: http://developers.facebook.com
2. Read thru the examples and other documentation at. http://developers.facebook.com/docs
3. Set up an app at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps
4. Get your feet wet by coding up some of the examples
5. Then get to work on your project's requirements and code up the solution.
6. Happy coding.